# python deepcopy of wx object

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a `wx.TreeCtrl` and want to make a real copy of it. I've tried it with

```
    CopyOfTree = copy.deepcopy(self.myTreeCtrl)
```

but this doesn't work. Is there a way to deep copy the `TreeCtrl`?

Comment: What is your use case? Why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: when working on a TestTree I want to have the option to "roll back" to the originally Tree, so making a backup from only the tree make sense for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the PersistenceManager. It allows you to save the widget's properties to make restoring it easier:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html

You can see an example in the wxPython demo under PersistentControls

Answer (score 2):

Look for example at this [wxpython-users post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/wxpython-users/saving$20the$20state$20of$20treectrl/wxpython-users/722CW7ru8tU/XvPUHCsrwXUJ), which tells you that deepcopy should not work on non-pure python data strucures. wxPython data structures are a combination of C++ and Python parts, of which deepcopy should only get hold of the Python parts.

If you want a different `TreeCtrl` with distinct data, you will have to create one (duh!). If you want ho have sort of a second view on the data, look at the DVC_DataViewModel example in the wxPython demo. It gives an example how to have multiple, automatically updating views views on the same data structure. The `DataViewCtrl` also has a TreeCtrl cousin (see the DVC_TreeCtrl example).